# Equivalent condition for an extension of local fields to be unramified

Tags: number-theory, local-field, ramification

Let $L/K$ be a degree $n$ finite Galois extension of local fields with corresponding residue field extension $\ell/k$ having residue class degree $f$ and ramification index $e$. We have a canonical map $\pi:\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)\to\operatorname{Gal}(\ell/k)$ given by restricting an automorphism $\sigma$ to the respective valuation rings then factoring out the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_L$. I have seen it claimed that $L/K$ is unramified iff $\pi$ is an isomorphism. One direction is clear from the equation $ef=n$: if $\pi$ is an isomorphism, then $f=n$ and thus $e=1$. However, it is not obvious to me how to prove the other direction. I've only seen a proof that $\pi$ is injective in the case that the extension is generated by roots of unity having order prime to the residue characteristic of $K$. Does unramified automatically imply injectivity or surjectivity in some simple way, or is there a more subtle argument?

Comment: $e=1$ implies that $|Gal(L/K)|=[L:K]=[\ell:k]=|Gal(\ell:k)|$. The surjectivity of $\pi$ is a general fact which follows from that the minimal polynomial of the reduction divides the reduction of the minimal polynomial which means the surjectivity of $Hom_{O_K}(O_K[a],O_L)\to Hom_{O_K/(\pi_K)}(O_K/(\pi_K)[a],O_L/(\pi_L))$. Also Hensel lemma implies that every unramified extension is generated by roots of unities.